# HTML Dom manipulation: IE7 issue

Tags: javascript, html, dom, internet-explorer-7

Why this sample of code doesn't work on IE7. Where is the problem? Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <title>Test</title>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

            function initialize() 
            {
                for(var i=0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    var tab = document.getElementById("search").childNodes[0];
                    var line = document.createElement("tr");
                    var column = document.createElement("td");
                    column.appendChild(document.createTextNode("DATA"));
                    line.appendChild(column);
                    tab.appendChild(line);
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()"> 
        <div id="search" class="bulle"><table><tr><td></td><td align="right">X</td></tr><tr><td><table id="tableResult"><table></td><td></td></tr></table></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error its showing? Or are there any warnings? Please add more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE you must add table rows to the tbody, not directly to the table. Also, in some browsers the first child of the div will be a text node if there is any whitespace between the DIV and TABLE tags in the markup. So either move the id to the table (or a tbody element), or use:

```
function initialize() {
    var div = document.getElementById("search");
    var tbody = div.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    // create rows, cells, etc.

    tbody.appendChild(line);
}
```

Note that all tables with rows will have a tbody element, even though the tags are optional in the markup (i.e. your markup doesn't have a tbody element, but the table in the DOM will have one).

There is a tutorial on MDN about using the DOM table methods: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_8:_Using_the_DOM_Table_Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Examples#Example_8%3a_Using_the_DOM_Table_Interface).